# Oracle APEX Single-Sign On

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on, oracle-apex

I have the following problem:
I have two Oracle Apex applications, each of them having its own log in and own database scheme. To make it easier for the enduser I would like to implement a Single-Sign On. Meaning, the user needs just **one username** and **one password** in order to log in **into both** applications.

In App A all user information is stored. The same user information should be accessible by App B. The two applications have different workspaces.
I am using APEX 4.2

How could I solve that problem?

Thanks for your answers.

Greetings from Germany

Admelo

Comment: Do you need share between applications only logins and passwords or other data too? Which authentication schemes do you use?

Comment: I need to share login data and user information like email adress or phone number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I can recommend to move one of applications to another workspace, development will become easier. If it impossible, you can allow one workspace to see objects of another workspace. Log in to APEX internal workspace, go to `Manage Workspaces` - `Manage Workspace to Schema Assignments`, and add desired schema to workspaces.
To share login data. It depends on authentication scheme of both applications:

- if you have scheme `Database user` in both applications, users can login in both applications right now
- if you have scheme `Application Express Login` - you have to move applications to one workspace
- if you have custom scheme - solution depends on scheme's implementation.

Comment: I am using a view in order to access the application of the other workspace.The view holds the login data of one application (App A) and the other application (App B) accesses that view.
So by using the view App B can access login data of App A.
But I stll don't know how to implement the login function in App B.
Do you have some tips?